# Python Label change upon radiobutton selection

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I need to change my labels background color each time I select a different radiobutton.

Here is a simplified example of my code.

```
Main_Window = Tk()
Main_Window.title("Main Window")
Main_Window.geometry("500x500+25+25")

Label_1 = Label(Main_Window, text="Label 1", width=8, bg=Label_1_Color, fg="black", bd=2, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=2)
Label_1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
Label_2 = Label(Main_Window, text="Label 2", width=8, bg=Label_2_Color, fg="black", bd=2, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=2)
Label_2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
Label_3 = Label(Main_Window, text="Label 3", width=8, bg=Label_3_Color, fg="black", bd=2, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=2)
Label_3.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
Label_4 = Label(Main_Window, text="Label 4", width=8, bg=Label_4_Color, fg="black", bd=2, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=2)
Label_4.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)

Radio_Group = IntVar()
Radio_1 = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option 1", bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=1)
Radio_1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)
Radio_1.invoke()
Radio_2 = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option 2", bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=2)
Radio_2.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)
Radio_3 = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option 3", bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=3)
Radio_3.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)
Radio_4 = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option 4", bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=4)
Radio_4.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)
Radio_5 = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option 5", bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=5)
Radio_5.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)

Main_Window.mainloop()
```

I would like for them to change to these conditions as many times as I select a different radiobutton.

```
if Radio_Group.get() == 1:
    Label_1_Color = "white"
    Label_2_Color = "white"
    Label_3_Color = "white"
    Label_4_Color = "white"
elif Radio_Group.get() == 2:
    Label_1_Color = "red"
    Label_2_Color = "white"
    Label_3_Color = "white"
    Label_4_Color = "white"
elif Radio_Group.get() == 3:
    Label_1_Color = "white"
    Label_2_Color = "red"
    Label_3_Color = "white"
    Label_4_Color = "white"
elif Radio_Group.get() == 4:
    Label_1_Color = "white"
    Label_2_Color = "white"
    Label_3_Color = "red"
    Label_4_Color = "white"
else:
    Label_1_Color = "white"
    Label_2_Color = "white"
    Label_3_Color = "white"
    Label_4_Color = "red"
```

Can I please get some hep on how to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: What is not working is that I have no clue on how to change my labels bg colors by selecting radiobuttons. I am not getting a specific error message. I am just asking how I can have my labels bg color change each time I select a radiobutton. The if statements just show what I would like to have my radiobuttons do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Tkinter docs at Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm), you can add a callback to each `Radiobutton`. Pass in a callable with the `command` keyword that does whatever you want. The option is listed under [`config`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm#Tkinter.Radiobutton.config-method), but is also available in [`__init__`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm#Tkinter.Radiobutton.__init__-method). In this case, you can turn the desired code into a function exactly as-is and use that as your command:

```
Main_Window = Tk()
Main_Window.title("Main Window")
Main_Window.geometry("500x500+25+25")

Label_1 = Label(Main_Window, text="Label 1", width=8, bg=Label_1_Color, fg="black", bd=2, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=2)
Label_1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
...

Radio_Group = IntVar()

def setColor():
    if Radio_Group.get() == 1:
        Label_1.configure(background="white")
        Label_2.configure(background="white")
        Label_3.configure(background="white")
        Label_4.configure(background="white")
    ...

Radio_1 = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option 1", bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=1, command=setColor)
Radio_1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)
Radio_1.invoke()
...
```

`...` means code that you already have in the question.

The [Effbot article on callback commands](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) has a whole section dealing with the exact situation of multiple buttons using the same callback. In your case, you have circumvented the issue by using `Radio_Group`.

To make your code look prettier and remove the giant nested if-statement, you can use lists, tuples, and loops. Note that the indexing has changed to 0-based. For example:

```
Main_Window = Tk()
Main_Window.title("Main Window")
Main_Window.geometry("500x500+25+25")

# A dictionary keyed by radio button containing sequences of colors for each label

labels = []
#labelCount = 4
for i in range(labelCount):
    label = Label(Main_Window, text="Label {}".format(i + 1), width=8, bg='white', fg="black", bd=2, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=2))
    label.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
    labels.append(label)

Radio_Group = IntVar()

def setColor():
    radioIndex = Radio_Group.get()
    for labelIndex in range(labelCount):
        if labelIndex == radioIndex - 1:
            color = 'red'
        else:
            color = 'white'
        labels[labelIndex].configure(background=color)

radios = []
#radioCount = 5
for i in range(radioCount):
    radio = Radiobutton(Main_Window, text="Option {}".format(i + 1), bg="white", variable=Radio_Group, value=i, command=setColor)
    radio.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W)
    if i == 0:
        radio.invoke()
    radios.append(radio)
```

Comment: Thanks. The first answer works great. The second one gives me an error though. labels[i].configure(background=color), IndexError: list index out of range. I'll try and figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: @GrandJoss. That's because it should be `labels[labelIndex].configure(backgroud=color)`. I fixed the post. Thanks for catching that.